# How to Unit Test a Long-Running Function Call?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

So I have a class that I'm calling `MessageEngine`.  This `MessageEngine` is going to have a single public function, called `StartEngine`.  The Engine will, every X seconds, poll server A, transform the results, and post to server B.  I have mocks for Server A and Server B's interfaces, so that I can test the `MessageEngine` in isolation.  However, the `StartEngine` call never actually terminates; the idea is that it run in perpetuity.  How can I best capture this in Unit Tests (using NUnit, if it matters)?  I don't want to expose the internals of the `MessageEngine` just to make it more testable.

My first thought is to just call `StartEngine`, wait an arbitrary amount of time, then assert the results were posted to Server B's mock.  Then I can call something like `StartEngine.Abort` to shut down the engine.  Is there a better pattern for testing these sorts of behaviours?

Comment: Even long running tasks have cancellationtokens for various reasons. In general the long running task is a Windows Service that will need to stop at some point.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to test systems where time plays a role I find it helpful to use reactive extensions. You can use a [TestScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reactive.testing.testscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to drive timelapses directly from your tests. Here is the [example](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/03/10/master-time-with-reactive-extensions/) that started me in this direction